# Intermittent java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException at javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat7, state-saving

I have a JSF 2.1.21 application with client state saving method. I'm also using PrimeFaces 3.5 + Tomcat 7.0.37.

I use OmniFaces full ajax exception handler to display a custom error page and email me with the stacktrace when a problem happens.

Every day I get at least one email with a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException. It seems to be related with redeployment of the application, but I'm not able to reproduce it.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
at javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState(AttachedObjectListHolder.java:165)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1566)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy$2.visit(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:380)
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1612)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.restoreView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:367)
at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:138)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:569)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:141)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:301)
at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.RestorableViewHandler.restoreView(RestorableViewHandler.java:59)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:192)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at br.com.spdata.tecnico.filter.MobileFilter.doFilter(MobileFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Phillip

Comment: Please share code  also.How can anyone know what your code is?

Comment: Is this all of the stack trace? No `caused by`?

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094077/jsf-session-fail-over-and-partial-state-saving It's related to dirty sessions after redeployment. Note OP's own answer at the bottom which specifies a context parameter which should fix this. Give it a try. It may or may not fix your particular problem.

Comment: @subodh I didn't add any code because this problem happens in different pages, with different managed bean scopes.

Comment: @kolossus I'm using Apache Commons Lang ExceptionUtils.getStackStrace(), but it seems it's not returning the full stack strace. I've changed the code to log this exception, so I when it happens again I can attach a new stacktrace and some code.

Comment: @BalusC thanks for the link, but I have only a single Tomcat instance. I'm using the default session persistence mechanism, but I don't restart the server on redeploy. I use parallel deploy, so only new sessions should go to the new version of the application. 

I'll try setting PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING to false, do you know if it will be more memory/cpu extensive?

Comment: Same error here on an f:ajax request on some specific pages. Setting `javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING` to false resolved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StackOverflow eventually reminds me of this question existence, so I'll take some minutes to answer how I solved it.

I guess it's not possible to replace a running JSF webapp without view state related exceptions if the page structure that the user was accessing changed somehow.

I was able to perfectly solve this using Tomcat's parallel deployment, where older versions of the webapp stay on the server until they have active sessions.

Comment: the corret  answer specified in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094077/jsf-session-fail-over-and-partial-state-saving

Comment: There is no "correct" answer in this case, but different approaches to handle  the situation...

Comment: Hehehe u r vaild here okay let me be specific "The link is the solution that worked for perfectly for the exact same exception".