# Weblogic Replication Issue with JSF application

Tags: session, weblogic, replication, weblogic12c

I have two servers on Weblogic cluster and deployed JSF based application on that cluster. I have created Cluster called Cluster01 which has Server01 and Server02 Servers. While accessing the application, my requests are going to Server01. So Server01 is having my Primary Session and Server02 have Session Replica. I am trying to test replication/failover by stopping primary Session server(i.e. Server01). After stopping when I click on any of the functionality on the JSF application gives View Expired Exception. I looked at the server logs which gives following error.

```
<Jul 13, 2016 9:04:08 AM EDT> <Error> <HTTP Session> <BEA-100028> <The session data could not be deserialized.java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to weblogic.servlet.internal.AttributeWrapper
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionData.getAttributeInternal(SessionData.java:449)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.ReplicatedSessionData.getAttribute(ReplicatedSessionData.java:713)
            at org.jboss.weld.context.beanstore.http.AbstractSessionBeanStore.getAttribute(AbstractSessionBeanStore.java:95)
            at org.jboss.weld.context.beanstore.AttributeBeanStore.attach(AttributeBeanStore.java:110)
            at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractBoundContext.activate(AbstractBoundContext.java:66)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I have Session Scoped Backing Bean. All the Domain objects are already serialized.

Environment:
Weblogic Server  12c
JSF2

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094077/jsf-session-fail-over-and-partial-state-saving

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic Server does not handle replication of jsf's managed beans. It is the responsibility of JSF.
Have a look at this JSF parameter to handle clustering replication :
com.sun.faces.enableAgressiveSessionDirtying

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has confirmed that they can reproduce the replication issue we are having.  Just waiting on them to fix it now.